# problem trying to make a reverse proxy on a flask gunicorn application with nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

i'm trying to make a reverse proxy and dockerize it for my flask application with nginx, gunicorn, docker and docker-compose . Before that the nginx part was in the same container than the web app, i'm trying to separe it.
My docker_compose yaml file is :

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 8008:8008
    networks:  
      - web_net

  flask_min:
    build: .
    image: flask_min
    container_name: flask_min
    expose:
      - "8008"
    networks:  
      - web_net
    depends_on:
      - nginx

networks:
  web_net:
    driver: bridge
```

My dockerfile is :

```
    FROM python:3.6
    MAINTAINER aurelien beliard (email@domain.com)
    RUN apt update
    COPY . /usr/flask_min
    WORKDIR /usr/flask_min
    RUN useradd -r -u 20979 -ms /bin/bash aurelien.beliard
    RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
   CMD gunicorn -w 3 -b :8008 app:app
```

my nginx docker file is

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./flask_min /etc/nginx/sites-available/
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flask_min /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask_min
```

my nginx config file in /etc/nginx sites-available and sites-enabled is named flask-min :

```
server {
    listen 8008; 
    server_name http://192.168.16.241/ ;
    charset utf-8; 
    location / { 
        proxy_pass http://flask_min:8008;
         } }
```

the requirements.txt file is :

```
Flask==0.12.2
grequests==0.3.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
Jinja2==2.10
```

The 2 containers are well created, gunicorn start well but i can't access to the application and there is nothing in the nginx access and error log .

If you have any idea it will be very appreciated.

ps sorry for the fault english is not my native language.

Comment: i put the minimal exemple on a github repo https://github.com/aurelBZH/flask_docker_reverseproxy  even if github have lots of problem today

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Maxm's answer, flask is depending on nginx to startup first. One way to fix it is to reverse the dependency order, but I think there's a more clever solution that doesn't require the dependency.

Nginx tries to do some optimization by caching the dns results of proxy_pass, but you can make it more flexible by setting it to a variable. This allows you to freely restart flask without having to also restart nginx.

Here's an example:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
set $upstream http://flask_min:8008;
proxy_pass $upstream;
```

Comment: i tried your changes but it seem to not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

`server_name` should just be the host. try `localhost` or just `_`.

you can also do multiple hosts: `server_name 192.168.16.241 localhost;`

The `depends_on` should be on `nginx` not `flask_min`. Remove it from flask and add:

```
depends_on:
  - flask_min
```

To nginx.

See if that works, let me know if you run into any more snags.

Comment: i change the host and the place of the depends_on but it change nothing. Nothing in the nginx log, no activity in the nginx docker container like if they weren't linked